# How do you display a jQuery datepicker with a blank date in MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model with a DateTime property as well as other properties, but here is the date one.

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

I am using EditorFor in my cshtml file

```
@model DatePickerDemo.Model.MyModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
}
```

I have an editor template

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToShortDateString(), new {@class = "datepicker" })
```

If I pass the View a model with a valid date this works beautifully. But I need to display a form with empty dates. My business model allows for null dates. When there are dates I want to display them, when there are null dates I want the date text boxes empty. This shouldn't be too hard to do. I see solutions where this is possible using straight html/js but not in MVC. 
I assume I need to change my model to have nullable dates but nothing I have tried so far gets me past an error on my `@Html.EditorFor` line. The error I get is this:

The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'System.DateTime'.

Comment: *`The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'System.DateTime'.`* If you changed your view Model to `DateTime? date` you would also need to change your template to `@model Nullable<DateTime>`.

Comment: An `EditorTemplate` is not even required here. Just `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker" });` (or what ever format you want)

Answer (score 1):

If you change your model to accept null values, you also need to adjust your template to match the type.

**view model**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```

But `Nullable<DateTime>` does not implement `.ToShortDateString()` method and you need to test for null.

**editor template**

```
@model DateTime?
@{
    var dateStr = Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : "";
}
@Html.TextBox("", dateStr, new { @class="datepicker" })
```